# How do I know if a control of a page made a Callback?

Tags: asp.net, controls

I have an ASPX page and on this page I have a control that contains an AJAX `UpdatePanel`.
When the control makes a callback my ASPX page's `Page_Load` event is triggered, but the `Page.IsCallBack` property is false.

How do I know in the page's `Page_Load` event if there was a callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the following code to check if a `Page_Load` is being triggered by an AJAX request:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Headers["X-MicrosoftAjax"]))
{
}
```